# How to say that you know something based on your intuition instead of a rule?

Tags: expressions

When we write something in our native language, we are able to write grammatically correct sentences not because we know the rules, but because it "feels" right.

How would you naturally express this in English? Imagine that you are teaching a student a foreign language and they make mistakes in verb conjugation. You say to them, "Don't write based on _____, follow the rules when conjugating." Don't write based on your feeling? Don't rely on your intuition? Don't write on a hunch?

Comment: If you are a native speaker, you follow the rules and it "feels right". The problem is not in following rules -- it's following the wrong rules. Rules which are taught in school are not the correct rules; they're just someone's opinion. The real rules are the ones that the native speakers follow, and those are the ones that linguists and lexicographers try to discover.

Comment: "Don't **make assumptions**, follow the rules when conjugating."

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the obvious: *Don't write based on **intuition**, follow the rules when conjugating.* What am I missing? What is wrong with the very word used in the title of the question?